# Need help creating a button component that when clicked, will scroll snap to the next section

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I have created a generic section component that has things like a heading, copy, etc. being passed in as props, and a child button component that is supposed to move the user to the next heading when clicked. When a user clicks the top or bottom arrow, it should snap scroll them to the next section.

I'm having some trouble brainstorming how to tackle my issue above, I thought using document.getElementsByClassName('snap-start') would work, since each of my section components has that as a class name, but I'm using Nextjs, so I can't even use the document interface.

My components are ordered and embedded within each other like:
Index.tsx

 BodySection.tsx

  SnapScrollButton.tsx

BodySection.tsx code:

```
    import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
    import Carousel from './Carousel';
    import SnapScrollButton from './SnapScrollButton';
    
    type BodySectionProps = {
        backgroundColor: string;
        heading: string;
        copy: string;
    hasCarousel: boolean;
    };
    
    const BodySection: React.FunctionComponent<BodySectionProps> = (props) => {
    const { backgroundColor, heading, copy, hasCarousel } = props;
    
    const btnUseRef = useRef(document.getElementsByClassName('snap-start'));
    
    const hasCopy = (copy: string) => {
        if (copy != null) {
        return <p>copy</p>;
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className={`p-8 h-full snap-start ${backgroundColor}`}>
          <h1 className="text-7xl">{heading}</h1>
          <p>{copy}</p>
          <Carousel hasCarousel={hasCarousel} />
          <SnapScrollButton btnRef={btnUseRef} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default BodySection;
```

SnapScrollButton.tsx code:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
    
    type SnapScrollButtonProps = {
      btnRef: any;
    };
    
    const SnapScrollButton: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
      const arrowRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    
      //document.getElementsByClassName('snap-start');
    
      const moveToNextSection = () => {
        arrowRef.current?.scrollIntoView();
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="text-center">
          <script>console.log(test);</script>
          <button>V</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SnapScrollButton;
```

Comment: I can't post an image to help illustrate the idea, but you can find an image posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/vw3p9o/nextjs_need_help_creating_a_button_component_that/) on my Reddit post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could tackle this. You CAN use the document selector in NextJS, you just have to use it in the right place. If you use a `useEffect` hook, you can use the document selector and make a Nodelist of your sections and go from there.

Or you use a ref on your current section and when the button is clicked, scroll the window down the height of your current div compared to the window height.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I'd prefer to use hooks where I can. If I went with a useRef, could I do something like useRef.next to go to the next div similar to an anchor tag? If I have to manually set the height for the button to move to next div, I'd be worried about getting that height correct on different viewports.

Comment: What do you think about the suggestion from Rhym posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/vw3p9o/nextjs_need_help_creating_a_button_component_that/)? Is that best practice? It seems like a bit of a hard codey way of doing things to me.. but not sure if I'm trying to overengineer this.